# Copy fixed number of files using xcopy

Tags: copy, xcopy

I have a large directory with lots of sub-directories and files in them. For testing purpose, I need to create a copy of the above with exact directory structure (empty dirs too) but copy only two files (does not matter which two) from each sub-directory. How can I do that using xcopy.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this can be directly done with using JUST [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true).
You would be able to copy the directory structure and NO files useing this command:

`xcopy /e /t path/to/folder path/to/copied/location`

That being said, doing something using C++ (i'd prefer Qt's [`QDir`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdir.html#details) class) and copy only 2 files from each directory would be quite trivial

Comment: Qt is available for windows. If you're trying to do this without programming something, I'm not quite sure its possible. You have quite strict requirements of only wanting to copy a few files out of each directory instead of copying the whole structure

Comment: Thx Paul but I cannot install any other software on the client's server. (You know how it works..)

Comment: You wouldn't need to install the software on their server, you can write the application on your machine. Are you accessing these files over a network or are you going to be locally at the machine? If you're accessing over the network, no problem at all with just doing what I've said on your machine. If you're going to be physically on the client machine, you wouldn't need to install the Qt SDK inorder to distribute a tool you make with it. You can just copy/paste the tool's exe and .dlls and you'd be set to go. No install necessary :)